# is there a good viewer/console/dashboard to use with coffee-resque?

Tags: node.js, resque

Is there something like resque-web that I can use for coffee-resque?  I tried pointing the ruby version of resque-web to my redis db and it seems to work, but none of my workers get registered and I can only see summary data after it's been processed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't such a thing, but you can make it yourself using [Socket.IO](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io) to show you the workers processing jobs in real-time.